# Akka Version mismatch in Class path Error

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-persistence

i am using SBT to setup Akka Persistence but it's failing with Error :

```
    Detected java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error, which MAY be caused by incompatible Akka versions on the classpath. Please note that a given Akka version MUST be the same across all modules of Akka that you are using, e.g. if you use akka-actor [2.5.6 (resolved from current classpath)] all other core Akka modules MUST be of the same version. External projects like Alpakka, Persistence plugins or Akka HTTP etc. have their own version numbers - please make sure you're using a compatible set of libraries.                 
    Uncaught error from thread [TopsActivitiesSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16]: akka.persistence.Eventsourced.persist$(Lakka/persistence/Eventsourced;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/Function1;)V, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for for ActorSystem[TopsActivitiesSystem]
    Detected java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error, which MAY be caused by incompatible Akka versions on the classpath. Please note that a given Akka version MUST be the same across all modules of Akka that you are using, e.g. if you use akka-actor [2.5.6 (resolved from current classpath)] all other core Akka modules MUST be of the same version. External projects like Alpakka, Persistence plugins or Akka HTTP etc. have their own version numbers - please make sure you're using a compatible set of libraries.                 
    Uncaught error from thread [TopsActivitiesSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]: akka.persistence.Eventsourced.persist$(Lakka/persistence/Eventsourced;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/Function1;)V, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for for ActorSystem[TopsActivitiesSystem]
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.persistence.Eventsourced.persist$(Lakka/persistence/Eventsourced;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/Function1;)V
```

My Configuration SBT Build file is :

```
    scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

    lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .configs(IntegrationTest)

    def akkaVersion = "2.5.6"
    def akkaHttpVersion = "10.0.10"
    def logbackVersion = "1.2.3"
    def ItAndTest = "it, test"

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-tools" % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-cluster-metrics_2.12" % akkaVersion,
    "com.redmart.fc" %% "fc-capacity-model" % "1.7.0",
    "com.redmart.akka" %% "akka-downing" % "1.1.0",
    "com.jsuereth" %% "scala-arm" % "2.0",
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",

    "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.7.2",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion,
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % logbackVersion,
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-access" % logbackVersion,
    "net.logstash.logback" % "logstash-logback-encoder" % "4.11",
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.3",

    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % akkaHttpVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-cassandra" % "0.58",
    //  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % akkaVersion,
    //  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-tools" % akkaVersion,
    "com.lightbend.akka" %% "akka-management-cluster-http" % "0.4",

    //  "org.iq80.leveldb" % "leveldb" % "0.9",
    //  "org.fusesource.leveldbjni" % "leveldbjni-all" % "1.8",
    "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.3.3",
    "com.enragedginger" %% "akka-quartz-scheduler" % "1.6.1-akka-2.5.x",
    //  "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "macros" % "2.2.2" % "provided",
    //  "com.softwaremill.macwire" %% "util" % "2.2.2",

    "com.esotericsoftware" % "kryo" % "4.0.1",
    "com.github.romix.akka" %% "akka-kryo-serialization" % "0.5.2",

    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % akkaHttpVersion % ItAndTest,
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % ItAndTest,
    "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.10.0" % ItAndTest,
    "com.github.dnvriend" %% "akka-persistence-inmemory" % "2.5.1.1" % ItAndTest
    )

    dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion
    dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion
    dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster" % akkaVersion
    dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-tools" % akkaVersion
    dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence" % akkaVersion
    dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion
    dependencyOverrides += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-cluster-metrics_2.12" % akkaVersion
```

Can Anyone explain the reason why it's failing? I am sure i am overriding to latest package. which is **2.5.6** using Dependency Overrides. i am Using **SBT 0.13**.

Comment: I recommend finding out using sbt's `show dependencyClasspath` command, as well as sbt-dependency-graph: https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the current version (0.5) of `akka-management-cluster-http`:

```
"com.lightbend.akka" %% "akka-management-cluster-http" % "0.5"
```

Version 0.4 depends on an older version of Akka.